# Is there a reason not to put timestamps in every table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, timestamp

I'm adding `created` and `updated` timestamp columns to some important tables and wondering to myself why I shouldn't put them in nearly every table 'just to have' since storage is cheap. Is that bad practice in some way? Am I being pedantic?

Specifically, I'm putting:

```
created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: The answer is, it depends.  If you are certain that you would never need the timestamp column, then don't bother adding it.  Besides saving storage, you also free yourself from possibly having to maintain it in other ways.

Comment: if you need to know when the table is updated by someone or records created use it. If you don't need any track of the update or when it was created then don't add it. If you are using 5.6+ you can have default for more than one column in a timestamp, so that for updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thanks guys! I decided to air on the side of 'more data' but still within reason. Also thanks for the tip on defaulting to NULL.

Comment: I see these columns in a lot of tables in this forum, but I rarely see any queries that _use_ them.  In my on DB work, I rarely need them.  Conclusion:  It sounds like a nifty idea, but those columns just collect dust.

Comment: I'll be pedanticer (cough). "Date created" and "date updated" are attributes of the row, not attributes of the thing the row is about. That is, if the table were about people, and we find a row for the person "stonefree", then "date created" doesn't tell you when "stonefree" was created, it tells you when the *row* that (for the time being) refers to "stonefree" was created. Also raises auditing issues, especially if you can update those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your idea is a good one.  Almost all tables that I create have the following columns:

- `createdAt`  -- datetime of creation
- `createdBy`  -- who inserted the row

And sometimes:

- `createdOn`  -- which system the row was created on

I tend to work less often with `update`s (I prefer to maintain all versions and fetch the most recent version), however that also seems like a good idea.

The major downside is that this occupies space on every row.  The space not only occupies space but it also means that fewer rows can be stored on each data page -- slightly slowing down some queries.  If your tables have thousands or millions of rows, that is probably not an issue.  If they have billions of rows, the overhead might be an issue.

In my opinion, the benefit to maintainability far outweighs the space issue.